# what is the minimum CPU speed we need to test an application for 100 virtual users load?

Tags: performance, cpu, web

The application uses Windows domain for its authentication, followed by one more layer of authentication.
I'm trying to run 100 virtual users on this application using JMeter, but seeing 100% CPU utilization as soon as i start the load. Ramp up period for each user is by 2 sec.
Tried with 50 users, but still the CPU gets choked as soon as i start the load.

The scenario is just to hit the landing page after login. no attachments

Any thoughts on what could be the problem here?. 
Is even 50 users too much for a Intel Xeon X650 2.67GHz server class processor supported by 8GB of memory?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to run 100 virtual users on this application using JMeter, but seeing 100% CPU utilization as soon as i start the load. Ramp up period for each user is by 2 sec. Tried with 50 users, but still the CPU gets choked as soon as i start the load.

Odds are you are running into a Client-Server model violation with no think time between requests and no delays between iterations.   Client-Server is based upon a shared computing model with expected delays between requests from any one given client.  It is during this delay period that resources can be used to service clients 2-*n*   As systems get busier and busier this resource gap shrinks and you close on system saturation.    It is very common to see model violations with development use of JMETER, since the design goals of developers are not typically business considerations to model actual user behavior, but instead are to check for conflicts on shared resources between objects/threads, etc...

Collapse think time and iteration pacing and you can go to 100% CPU almost immediately without regard to the number of CPUs on a box with a relatively small load.